# Rails error 500 after image upload in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, nginx

I can't understand what's happening. Some days earlier my production server was fine, with everything working great. Then some changes was needed (production database reset), after that, the image upload feature of my app started to respond with error 500, but only in production. In development the upload occurs with no errors, but production can't do this anymore and I don't know why.

Here is my **development.log** of a image uploading:

```
Started POST "/smokes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-25 21:45:40 -0300
Processing by SmokesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bKKTUuAYPvKQRJJ+t8PgPqBImrI/XTfPo030rxb1HYA=", "smoke"=>{"latitude"=>"55.677584411089505", "longitude"=>"46.23046875", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f8a6365c918 @original_filename="138431703817.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"smoke[image]\"; filename=\"138431703817.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n", @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/qh/j7fp47qn3gn2rbnqyccr5mr80000gn/T/RackMultipart20131125-11066-1i15nwb>>, "description"=>""}} 
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
fschuindt
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (3.6ms)  INSERT INTO "smokes" ("created_at", "description", "image", "latitude", "longitude", "picture_content_type", "picture_file_name", "picture_file_size", "picture_updated_at", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Tue, 26 Nov 2013 00:45:42 UTC +00:00], ["description", ""], ["image", "_1f47882dc38d1eb143ee.jpg"], ["latitude", 55.677584411089505], ["longitude", 46.23046875], ["picture_content_type", nil], ["picture_file_name", nil], ["picture_file_size", nil], ["picture_updated_at", nil], ["updated_at", Tue, 26 Nov 2013 00:45:42 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", nil]]
  SQL (3.8ms)  INSERT INTO "versions" ("created_at", "event", "ip", "item_id", "item_type", "object", "whodunnit") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Tue, 26 Nov 2013 00:45:42 UTC +00:00], ["event", "create"], ["ip", "127.0.0.1"], ["item_id", 12], ["item_type", "Smoke"], ["object", nil], ["whodunnit", #<User id: 1, name: "That's a test :) LOL", email: "f.schuindtcs@gmail.com", password_digest: nil, created_at: "2013-10-11 00:35:06", updated_at: "2013-11-24 18:42:33", external_provider: true, avatar_setup: nil>]]
   (2.3ms)  COMMIT
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  Smoke Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "smokes".* FROM "smokes" WHERE "smokes"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 12]]
   (0.6ms)  UPDATE "smokes" SET "user_id" = 1, "image" = '12_1f47882dc38d1eb143ee.jpg', "updated_at" = '2013-11-26 00:46:20.883785' WHERE "smokes"."id" = 12
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "versions" ("created_at", "event", "ip", "item_id", "item_type", "object", "whodunnit") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Tue, 26 Nov 2013 00:46:20 UTC +00:00], ["event", "update"], ["ip", "127.0.0.1"], ["item_id", 12], ["item_type", "Smoke"], ["object", "---\nlatitude: 55.677584411089505\nlongitude: 46.23046875\ndescription: ''\ncreated_at: 2013-11-26 00:45:42.246820000 Z\nupdated_at: 2013-11-26 00:45:42.246820000 Z\npicture_file_name: \npicture_content_type: \npicture_file_size: \npicture_updated_at: \nuser_id: \nimage: _1f47882dc38d1eb143ee.jpg\nid: 12\n"], ["whodunnit", #<User id: 1, name: "That's a test :) LOL", email: "f.schuindtcs@gmail.com", password_digest: nil, created_at: "2013-10-11 00:35:06", updated_at: "2013-11-24 18:42:33", external_provider: true, avatar_setup: nil>]]
   (1.7ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://weedmap.dev/smokes/12
Completed 302 Found in 45114ms (ActiveRecord: 15.2ms)
```

And this is my **production.log** uploading a image, note that the error is not explained, it just render the error:

```
Started POST "/smokes" for 189.71.176.229 at 2013-11-26 00:42:33 +0000
Processing by SmokesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"YMH9OlQFPnd9fubk8dqVNeS6/xwyTU+/xbMegPIBeUs=", "smoke"=>{"latitude"=>"58.539594766640484", "longitude"=>"42.1875", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x90f52cc @original_filename="aruana.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"smoke[image]\"; filename=\"aruana.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20131126-25516-v3ycvc>>, "description"=>"Wut"}}
  Rendered pages/_bottom.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered errors/error_500.html.erb within layouts/application (3.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_head.html.erb (2.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4710ms (Views: 8.4ms | ActiveRecord: 3.7ms)
```

The image was the same, everything was the same.
I was thinking about the permissions of the Rails /tmp, but it occurs even after "sudo chmod 777 /tmp" LOL.

My nginx error.log don't tell nothing about it too.
What should I do?

Where to look for clues?

**Extra Information:** My app store images in Amazon S3 (even in development); It uses Carrierwave;

**EDIT:**

As mentioned by diego.greyrobot, I used the rescue exception and looks like I have found a big clue. I don't understand it yet, but I will keep trying to figure out what's happening.

Check the code in my controller...

**smokes_controller.rb**:

```
 def create
    @user = current_user
    @smoke = Smoke.new(params[:smoke])
    logger.debug ENV['USER']

    begin
      if @smoke.save
        @user.smokes << @smoke
        redirect_to @smoke
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    rescue Exception => e
      puts e.class
      puts e.message
      puts e.backtrace
    end

  end
```

Ans the big exception message:

```
Excon::Errors::MovedPermanently
Expected(200) <=> Actual(301 Moved Permanently)
  response => #<Excon::Response:0x007f9bed62c1a0 @data={:body=>"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>PermanentRedirect</Code><Message>The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.</Message><RequestId>C463040B8E840FC4</RequestId><Bucket>weedsquare-pro</Bucket><HostId>TRnfX/oK0un+To6/2W6JWi8gBe4YSvZfW3nSqDCLCzfofhZbOnt/RXAb1U8G2OdO</HostId><Endpoint>s3.amazonaws.com</Endpoint></Error>", :headers=>{"x-amz-request-id"=>"C463040B8E840FC4", "x-amz-id-2"=>"TRnfX/oK0un+To6/2W6JWi8gBe4YSvZfW3nSqDCLCzfofhZbOnt/RXAb1U8G2OdO", "Content-Type"=>"application/xml", "Transfer-Encoding"=>"chunked", "Date"=>"Tue, 26 Nov 2013 05:34:59 GMT", "Connection"=>"close", "Server"=>"AmazonS3"}, :status=>301, :remote_ip=>"204.246.162.224"}, @body="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>PermanentRedirect</Code><Message>The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.</Message><RequestId>C463040B8E840FC4</RequestId><Bucket>weedsquare-pro</Bucket><HostId>TRnfX/oK0un+To6/2W6JWi8gBe4YSvZfW3nSqDCLCzfofhZbOnt/RXAb1U8G2OdO</HostId><Endpoint>s3.amazonaws.com</Endpoint></Error>", @headers={"x-amz-request-id"=>"C463040B8E840FC4", "x-amz-id-2"=>"TRnfX/oK0un+To6/2W6JWi8gBe4YSvZfW3nSqDCLCzfofhZbOnt/RXAb1U8G2OdO", "Content-Type"=>"application/xml", "Transfer-Encoding"=>"chunked", "Date"=>"Tue, 26 Nov 2013 05:34:59 GMT", "Connection"=>"close", "Server"=>"AmazonS3"}, @status=301, @remote_ip="204.246.162.224">
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/middlewares/expects.rb:6:in `response_call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:353:in `response'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:247:in `request'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/middlewares/idempotent.rb:12:in `error_call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:10:in `error_call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:260:in `rescue in request'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:220:in `request'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/middlewares/idempotent.rb:12:in `error_call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:10:in `error_call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:260:in `rescue in request'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:220:in `request'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/middlewares/idempotent.rb:12:in `error_call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:10:in `error_call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:260:in `rescue in request'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:220:in `request'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/fog-1.12.1/lib/fog/core/connection.rb:25:in `request'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/fog-1.12.1/lib/fog/aws/storage.rb:506:in `request'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/fog-1.12.1/lib/fog/aws/requests/storage/put_object.rb:32:in `put_object'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/fog-1.12.1/lib/fog/aws/models/storage/file.rb:211:in `save'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/fog-1.12.1/lib/fog/core/collection.rb:52:in `create'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/carrierwave-0.8.0/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb:258:in `store'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/carrierwave-0.8.0/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb:79:in `store!'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/carrierwave-0.8.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/store.rb:59:in `block in store!'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/carrierwave-0.8.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:17:in `with_callbacks'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/carrierwave-0.8.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/store.rb:58:in `store!'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/carrierwave-0.8.0/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:371:in `store!'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/carrierwave-0.8.0/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:223:in `store_image!'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:438:in `_run__1809318562336863559__save__1439115245121770263__callbacks'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_save_callbacks'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `create_or_update'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:84:in `save'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in `block (2 levels) in save'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in `block in save'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:258:in `save'
/Users/fschuindt/Documents/weedmap/app/controllers/smokes_controller.rb:24:in `create'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:480:in `_run__2082980582115641481__process_action__2063028963365509982__callbacks'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:612:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/omniauth-1.1.3/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:177:in `call!'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/omniauth-1.1.3/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:157:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/omniauth-1.1.3/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:177:in `call!'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/omniauth-1.1.3/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:157:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/omniauth-1.1.3/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:48:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__222776516211350810__call__1439115245121770263__callbacks'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:102:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:143:in `pass'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:155:in `invalidate'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:71:in `call!'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
Started POST "/smokes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-26 02:34:52 -0300
Processing by SmokesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"FjLDOwzP/wuus5u90qsOjyxOiHghmKuJnnx/ThVORrg=", "smoke"=>{"latitude"=>"52.696361078274485", "longitude"=>"48.33984375", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f9bf06c2030 @original_filename="136596215039.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"smoke[image]\"; filename=\"136596215039.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/qh/j7fp47qn3gn2rbnqyccr5mr80000gn/T/RackMultipart20131126-12646-1dalk6q>>, "description"=>"What?"}}
  Rendered pages/_bottom.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered errors/error_500.html.erb within layouts/application (1.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_head.html.erb (1.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7303ms (Views: 6.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/assets/sad.jpg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-26 02:35:00 -0300
Served asset /sad.jpg - 304 Not Modified (2ms)
```

Comment: Can you wrap your controller action in a rescue => e and then puts out what is e.class, e.message, and e.backtrace

Comment: Does it work in Production ENV on your local machine?  Can you load the database on your local machine to test?

Comment: @diego.greyrobot I have edited the question with the exception raised, thank you.

Comment: @fatfrog No, "RAILS_ENV=production rails s" raise the error too. And yes.

Comment: What happens if you use your development database in production env on your local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually my problem was in the carrierwave.rb, I was setting a region to Amazon S3 ":region => 'us-west-1'". For some reason this was causing all the trouble, just let it choice the region by default and everything will work great.